# API usage limit error in twitter 4j

Tags: java, twitter4j

this is my program to update my twitter status using my application using twitter 4j

```
package hussi;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import twitter4j.Status;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.auth.AccessToken;
import twitter4j.auth.RequestToken;


public class test {
    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(test.class.getName());
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new test().publish();
    }

    private void publish(){

        String message="the long long week is over :) :) :)";

        try {
            Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
            try {
                RequestToken requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();
                AccessToken accessToken = null;
                while (null == accessToken) {
                    logger.fine("Open the following URL and grant access to your account:");
                    logger.fine(requestToken.getAuthorizationURL());
                    try {
                        accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken);
                    } 
                    catch (TwitterException te) {
                        if (401 == te.getStatusCode()) {
                            logger.severe("Unable to get the access token.");
                        } else {
                            te.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                logger.info("Got access token.");
                logger.info("Access token: " + accessToken.getToken());
                logger.info("Access token secret: " + accessToken.getTokenSecret());
            } 
            catch (IllegalStateException ie) {
                // access token is already available, or consumer key/secret is not set.
                if (!twitter.getAuthorization().isEnabled()) {
                    logger.severe("OAuth consumer key/secret is not set.");
                    return;
                }
            }
            Status status = twitter.updateStatus(message);
            logger.info("Successfully updated the status to [" + status.getText() + "].");
        } 
        catch (TwitterException te) {
            te.printStackTrace();
            logger.severe("Failed to get timeline: " + te.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

but i am getting an error at this line

```
Status status = twitter.updateStatus(message);
```

the error says

```
SEVERE: Failed to get timeline: 403:The request is understood, but it has been refused. An accompanying error message will explain why. This code is used when requests are being denied due to update limits (https://support.twitter.com/articles/15364-about-twitter-limits-update-api-dm-and-following).
{"errors":[{"message":"SSL is required","code":92}]}
```

any suggestion guys ??

it says to visit [this link](https://support.twitter.com/articles/15364-about-twitter-limits-update-api-dm-and-following)

but i didn't what exactly causes this

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to authenticate successfully? I use the following codes to  create twitter object: Try it!

```
public static ConfigurationBuilder confBuilder = null;
public static Configuration config = null;
public static Twitter twitterObj = null;

confBuilder = new twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder();
confBuilder.setDebugEnabled(true);

confBuilder.setOAuthConsumerKey(consumerKey);
confBuilder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(consumerSecret);
confBuilder.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);
confBuilder.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(accessTokenSecret);

config = confBuilder.build();

twitter4j.TwitterFactory tf = new twitter4j.TwitterFactory(config);
twitterObj = tf.getInstance();
```

Comment: the prob is not with how i am creating the object , its fine either way , it asks to include SSL , i dont know how to  do that in my app

Comment: It is really weird. I dont know why it requires SSL.

Comment: well that makes the two of us

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Twitter updates their SSL certificates. You should update it on your machine too.

On an Ubuntu server, it looks like

```
$ sudo apt-get install ca-certificates
```

See also https://dev.twitter.com/docs/security/using-ssl

Answer (score 0):

Twitter made SSL connections as mandatory for OAuth.

Latest versions of twitter4j jars have ssl connection by default.

Using twitter4j 4.x will solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had face same error and upgrading to the latest version of twitter4j 3.0.5  fixed the issue.

Get the latest here http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html#download

I should mention that the version i was running was twitter4j 3.0.3. So going to version 3.0.5 or 3.0.6 fixed the issue .